# Can the order of criteria in a WHERE clause affect performance in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, where-clause, sql-like

Given the following query:

```
select ....................
from ......................
where 
(
      lower(c01) like ? 
      or lower(c02) like ? 
      or lower(c5x3_.c01) like ? 
      or lower(5x3_.c02) like ?
 )    
 and(
(
      lower(c03) like ? 
      or lower(c04) like ? 
      or lower(c5x3_.c03) like ? 
      or lower(5x3_.c04) like ?
 )    
 /* ...Multiple further LIKEs... */
 and status=1; /* status is a non-nullable value whose values can only be 1 or 2 */
```

The first 10 or 12 restrictions are `LIKE`s on various patterns - I know this can be slow so always put the status criterion first, i.e:

```
status=1;
 and(other LIKEs)
```

My question: Could there be a performance gain in applying the simpler restrictions first (e.g. in this case, the int value being compared can't be null value and only has 2 possible values)? Or will performance be the same if the `LIKE`s are put first and the status check appears later?

Let's suppose there are no indexes on any column to simplify the question.

Comment: There should be no difference, check with explain as Ivan suggested. For an Oracle database operating in rule-based mode the order in the where clause can make a difference, but the rule-based mode has been deprecated for a long time. As far as I know MySQL has never had that "feature".

Comment: You have a table named `5x3_`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Part answer, part asking for more info...)

It makes no difference whether you put `status=1` first or last.  Phrased another way, the order of `ANDed` things in a `WHERE` is unimportant.

`LOWER(x) LIKE '...'` is much less efficient than setting the collation of `x` to be case-folding, such as `utf8_general_ci` (the `ci` means "case insensitive").  With a `ci` collation, you need do only `x LIKE '...'`.

But, that won't speed things up much.  You have lots of `ORs`; these are inefficient because an index is *usually* useless, thereby necessitating a full table scan.

Often, `OR` can be turned into `UNION` to be able to use indexes.  But probably not in your case.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Hmmm... The pattern of the query makes me wonder if you have a lot of 'identical' tables.  If so, perhaps we can jump on that as an inefficient way to design a schema.  So, please tell us if `c01` and `c03` (etc) look the same.

What kinds of values will be put into the `LIKEs`?  Words?  Numbers?  Arbitrary strings?  Wildcards?  Leading wildcards?  Not leading?  If "words", then `FULLTEXT` *might* be useful.  But...  We will need to look hard at the long(?) list of tables involved.

Answer (score 3):

The order in which conditions are placed *can* make a difference because of MySQL short-circuiting. Here is an attempt to prove this:

http://rextester.com/HJGN96158

This runs the following queries:

```
SELECT myint FROM mytable WHERE myint >= 3 AND myslowfunction('query #1', myint) = 1;
SELECT myint FROM mytable WHERE myslowfunction('query #2', myint) = 1 AND myint >= 3;
```

The only difference between these is the order of operands in the AND condition.

`myslowfunction` deliberately sleeps for a second and has the side effect of adding an entry to a log table each time it is run. Here are the results of what is logged when running the above two queries:

```
myslowfunction called for query #1 with value 3
myslowfunction called for query #1 with value 4
myslowfunction called for query #2 with value 1
myslowfunction called for query #2 with value 2
myslowfunction called for query #2 with value 3
myslowfunction called for query #2 with value 4
```

The above shows that a slow function is executed more times when it appears on the left side of an AND condition when the other operand isn't always false (due to short-circuiting).

From this, my advice would be to put the `status = 1` check before the `LIKE` checks as (indexes aside) it is likely to be evaluated faster.

Answer (score 2):

> is just the same thing put the ilikes first and the status criteria later?

You can find out the answer yourself by running [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) against the two 
versions of your query. E.g.

```
EXPLAIN select ... from ... where
```

Most probably you'll get two exactly same execution plans meaning the two statements are equivalent because the status part should be removed by the [dead code elimination optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-eliminating-dead-code.html).

Comment: I don't see any dead code.  `status` can be either 1 or 2.

Answer (score 2):

SQL is a **declarative language**, you only care about **"what to do"**, so you don't have to worry about **"how"** your query is going to be executed, the DBMS will take care of that and choose **the best execution plan**, so a short answer is there is no difference in the order.

Comment: True, but MySQL is not smart about rearranging things to evaluate the most selective first.  Only for handling constants and making use of indexes.

Comment: Yes, so I think that the proper use of indexes would overcome this problem since MySQL would make use of indexes firstly regardless of the order.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the condition with the smallest cardinality at first. This filters the number of rows to browse to a smaller numer.